# What reversible cellular automaton rule emulates all 256 Wolfram rules?

Tags: cellular-automata

On page [648 of A New Kind of Science](https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/p648--a-universal-cellular-automaton/), there's a definition of a "universal" cellular automaton, which can emulate Wolfram's 256 elementary cellular automata. Furthermore, it emulates them in a "cell-by-cell" manner: one cell of the elementary automaton is represented by 20 consecutive cells in this cellular automaton.

[Elsewhere, on page 437](https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/p437--the-notion-of-reversibility/), there's a definition for a family of reversible 2-color cellular automata. I expect that in a family like this, but with more colors, you can construct a cellular automaton that is "universal" in the exact same sense as the one on page 648: one that can emulate all 256 elementary cellular automata, and which represents them on a "cell-by-cell" level, using consecutive cells to represent one cell.

I feel sure someone has made something like this, but I don't know the cellular automata literature. Could someone point me to it?

Comment: Of course, there's a trivial way to do this using 512 states per cell (and an only slightly less trivial one using 32 + 2 = 34 states). It's even quite efficient, running as fast as the emulated automaton and representing each emulated cell by one emulator cell. But I assume you're looking for something a little less trivial and more "universal" than this.

Comment: Are you sure that your 512 states solution is reversible? If one removes the requirement of reversibility, I agree with you.

Comment: @user148606: I originally read the question as asking for a reversible CA rule that emulates all the 256 elementary _reversible_ (2nd order) CA rules. However, on a closer look, I see that it doesn't actually say that.

Comment: In theory rule $110$ can emulate all other Elementary Cellular Automata, because it is universal. But rule $110$ is not reversible, so that one is out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no precise definition of what "emulating" means in the book of Wolfram, but it looks like intrinsic simulations (like in the notion of intrinsic universality, see [this survey on universality in CA](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/271840/filename/unca.pdf)). In this case, the answer is NO, because there is no reversible CA that can emulate an irreversible CA.

Comment: Makes sense, and reference is very interesting for making these ideas precise.